# How does -exec actually work

Tags: linux, command-line, find, exec

I am confused on the `-exec` command. E.g. in this case:

`find . -type f -name "*.c" -exec cat {} \;>all_c_files.txt`

It seems that I get `cat file1 file2 file3 ... fileN`

While in this case:

`find . -type f -name "*.txt" -exec cp {} OLD  \;`

I get:

```
`cp file1 OLD`  
`cp file2 OLD`  
`cp file3 OLD`  
...  
`cp fileN OLD`
```

Similar case e.g. in:

`find . -type f -name "*.txt" -exec printf "Text file: %s\n" {} \;`

Seems to do:

```
printf "Text file: file1"  
printf "Text file: file2"  
printf "Text file: file3"  
...  
printf "Text file: fileN"
```

So how does `exec` work? I mean am I right that it behaves differently in these example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose that you are confused by `cat` command (and shell redirection), and not by `find` one.

`find . -type f -name "*.c" -exec cat {} \; > all_c_files.txt` is equivalent to:

```
(
  cat file1 ;
  cat file2 ;
  cat file3 ;
  ... 
  cat fileN
) > all_c_files.txt
```

obviously the previous command and the following one have the same identical result:

```
cat file1 file2 file3 ... fileN > all_c_files.txt
```